# "display false" is not hiding but placing as first column

Tags: grails, dynamic, hide, scaffolding

I've built a small grails (3.1.4) application. I have the following domain model and am using dynamic scaffolding:

```
class Player {

    String name
    String identifier
    int points

    static constraints = {
      identifier(display: false)
    }

    static mapping = {
      version false 
   }
}
```

I want to hide the identifier as shown in the code. However, the column is not hidden. Instead it is shown as the first column in the table.

**EDIT:**
I've filed a bug at https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues/21

Comment: I assume you are talking about the default scaffolding and if you are, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown To avoid missunderstandings. I was following this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Grails/article.html#guestbookapplication_controllerview It was talking about dynamic scaffolding, which is activated by `def scaffold = Player`. Maybe the wording of the tutorial is wrong/dated.

Comment: That behavior is governed by the scaffolding plugin.  If you file an issue at the link I mentioned, we can investigate that.